# Traducción correcta de "Claims" en el contexto de una autenticación

Tags: traducción

Me encuentro a menudo con una traducción de **"Claims"** como **"Notificaciones"**. En la propia [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netcore-3.1) utilizan este término. Viendo el resto del documento claramente se trata de una traducción automática.

Esta es la definición en la [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity) pero está sin traducir al español.

Algunos blogs en español se han adherido a la traducción de **"Notificaciones"** pero yo no le veo relación alguna. Esta información de usuario para nada viene en forma de Notificaciones de ningún tipo. Suele ser fruto del proceso de autenticación (por ejemplo: un login) de un usuario con una "autoridad".

**Contexto:**

Un **Claim** es un dato que forma parte del perfil de un usuario, por ejemplo: su nombre, su email, su edad, una foto, etc. Lo que tienen de peculiar estos datos es que han sido emitidos por una "autoridad" y puede asegurarse (ya que el proceso ha sido validado digitalmente) que son ciertos. Claro está, siempre dentro del contexto de esa "autoridad".

Por ejemplo, si la autoridad es una administración se puede decir que el "Claim" **name** es el nombre del usuario actual porque así lo ha certificado el proveedor de identidad oficial de un gobierno. Sin embargo, si la autoridad es Facebook, el "Claim" **name** podría ser perfectamente "Super Mario" y seguiría siendo cierto dentro del contexto de Facebook, ya que el usuario se dio de alta con ese nombre.

Una traducción de las disponibles en el diccionario y que me gusta más es **"Afirmaciones"**, sin embargo tampoco me convence demasiado.

Answer (score 2):

Una traducción posible dentro del contexto descripto podría ser:

- dato verificado

Otros sinónimos para *verificado* son *autenticado, confirmado, cotejado, corroborado*.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque generalmente (en las documentaciones traducidas por un humano) se suele usar *claims* en inglés, creo que la traducción que refleja el significado original es "privilegios".
Por ejemplo, Wikipedia en su artículo de [JSON Web Token](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) dice:

> JSON Web Token (abreviado JWT) es un estándar abierto basado en JSON propuesto por IETF (RFC 7519) para la creación de tokens de acceso que permiten la propagación de identidad y **privilegios** o claims en inglés.

Comment: Interesante descubrimiento, y bienvenido/a!. Parece que un *privilegio* es solo un tipo de *claim*, pero hay otros, como se indica [aquí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity): "the statement can be about a name, group, buying preference, ethnicity, **privilege**, association or capability". Incluso la [versión en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Standard_fields) del artículo que enlazas tiene una lista de *claims* que no son privilegios.